# All binary numbers with exactly n digits

Tags: binary, prolog, sequence

I need a predicate to produce all binary numbers with length `N` in a list.

Sample use:

```
?- bins(2,L).
L = [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]].    % expected result
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `findall/3`!

We define `bins/2` based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), [`foldl/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4), [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord), [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), and [`(#<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915).

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

bins(N,Zss) :-
   if_(N #< 1,
       ( N #= 0, Zss = [[]] ),
       ( N #= N0+1,
         bins(N0,Xss),
         foldl(\Bs^phrase(([[0|Bs]],[[1|Bs]])),Xss,Zss,[]))).
```

Sample use:

```
?- bins(4,Zss).
Zss = [[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],
       [0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],
       [0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1],
       [0,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]].
```

Here is the most general query:

```
?- bins(N,Zss).
  N = 0, Zss = [[]]
; N = 1, Zss = [[0],[1]]
; N = 2, Zss = [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]
; N = 3, Zss = [[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]
...
```

Comment: Note the anomaly: `bins(1+0,L)` fails, whereas `bins(2+0,L)` succeeds

Comment: New version improves even upon determinism!

Comment: @false. And `N = 0, Zss = [[]]` as base-case, not `N = 1, Zss = [[0],[1]]`. Somewhat more canonical, is it not?

Comment: ... you mean: well-founded

Comment: @false. Ah... yes, exactly! It *was* on the tip of me tongue.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably better ways, but here is a solution using findall

```
bins(N,L) :-
    findall(Num,binary_number(N,Num),L).

binary_number(0,[]).
binary_number(N,[D|Ds]) :-
    N > 0,
    member(D,[0,1]),
    N1 is N - 1,
    binary_number(N1,Ds).
```

Comment: i need a solution without findall

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively :

```
member_(A, B) :- member(B, A).
bins(Size, Result) :-
    findall(L, (length(L, Size), maplist(member_([0, 1]), L)), Result).
```

Could be simplified with the use of the [lambda](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) module :

```
bins(Size, Result) :-
    findall(L, (length(L, Size), maplist(\X^member(X, [0, 1]), L)), Result).
```

Comment: i need a solution without findall or other "ready" predicates