# Splitting a list of integers into a list of positive integers and a list of negative integers

Tags: list, split, prolog, clpfd

I've been trying to create a predicate in Prolog which splits a list of integers into a list of positive integers and into a list of negative integers.

Sample query with expected result:

```
?- split([1,-2,3,4,-8],X,Y).
X = [1,3,4],
Y = [-2,-8].
```

This is the code I got so far:

```
split([], [], []).
split([Head|Tail], List1, List2) :- split(Tail, [Head|List1], List2), Head>=0.
split([Head|Tail], List1, List2) :- split(Tail, List1, [Head|List2]), Head<0.
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What should happen if the input list contains a zero?

Comment: It should be put in the list of positive integers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recursive part is not quite correct.

```
split([], [], []).
split([Head|Tail], [Head|List1], List2) :- Head>=0, split(Tail, List1, List2).
split([Head|Tail], List1, [Head|List2]) :- Head<0, split(Tail, List1, List2).
```

The `Head` should be added to the positive list if `Head >= 0` and to the negative list when `Head < 0`.

Moreover, checking the sign of `Head` *at the beginning* is better, because it will prevent unnecessary recursive calls.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks for explaining the optimization as well.

Comment: @MizaCoroda Use `trace` to understand the recursions :)

Comment: @FlopCode: Your solution is nice, but on current Prolog implementations it consumes additional auxiliary space proportional to the number of non-negative elements. It is probably best to use `compare/3` here.

Comment: Can you please illustrate the derivation tree of the given solution? That would be a great help.

Answer (score 6):

In SWI-Prolog you can use the predicate `partition/4` (which is typically autoloaded from the `apply` module):

```
?- partition(=<(0), [1,-2,3,4,-8,0], X, Y).
X = [1, 3, 4, 0],
Y = [-2, -8].
```

Comment: SWI-Prolog `partition/4` predicate is not a built-in predicate. It's a library predicate defined in the `apply` module (which is most likely being auto-loaded).

Comment: @PauloMoura  Tnx, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a definition using constraints.  In this case, it is `library(clpfd)` of SWI and YAP (maybe also XSB). This library is so general that it subsumes regular integer uses.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Using reification:

```
split([], [], []).
split([E|Es], Poss, Negs) :-
   E #>= 0 #<==> B,
   i_split(B, E, Es, Poss, Negs).

i_split(1, E, Es, [E|Poss], Negs) :-
   split(Es, Poss, Negs).
i_split(0, E, Es, Poss, [E|Negs]) :-
   split(Es, Poss, Negs).
```

Alternatively, you can use `zcompare/3`, I prefer that version:

```
split([], [], []).
split([E|Es], Poss, Negs) :-
   zcompare(Order, E, 0),
   c_split(Order, E, Es, Poss, Negs).

c_split(>, E, Es, [E|Poss], Negs) :-
   split(Es, Poss, Negs).
c_split(=, E, Es, [E|Poss], Negs) :-
   split(Es, Poss, Negs).
c_split(<, E, Es, Poss, [E|Negs]) :-
   split(Es, Poss, Negs).
```

You can use it for the regular queries, and for more general ones, like

```
?- split(Es,[A],[]).
   Es = [A], A in 1..sup
;  Es = [0], A = 0
;  false.
```

Answer (score 2):

Stay **logically pure** and efficient. How? By using meta-predicate [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and `(#=<)/3`!

First, let us define `(#=<)/3`, the reified version of `(#=<)/2`, based
on [`bool01_t/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459595/4609915).
For the sake of completeness, let's also define `(#<)/3`, `(#>)/3`, and `(#>=)/3`!

```
#=<(X,Y,Truth) :- X #=< Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

#<( X,Y,Truth) :- X #<  Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

#>( X,Y,Truth) :- X #>  Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).

#>=(X,Y,Truth) :- X #>= Y #<==> B, bool01_t(B,Truth).
```

*That's it!* Now, let's do the split the OP wanted:

```
?- tpartition(#=<(0),[1,-2,3,4,-8,0],Ts,Fs).
Ts = [1,3,4,0], Fs = [-2,-8].                   % succeeds deterministically
```

This is **monotone**, so we  get *sound answers* even when using general, non-ground terms:

```
?- tpartition(#=<(0),[A,B,C],Ts,Fs).
Ts = [     ], Fs = [A,B,C], A in inf.. -1, B in inf.. -1, C in inf.. -1 ;
Ts = [    C], Fs = [A,B  ], A in inf.. -1, B in inf.. -1, C in   0..sup ;
Ts = [  B  ], Fs = [A,  C], A in inf.. -1, B in   0..sup, C in inf.. -1 ;
Ts = [  B,C], Fs = [A    ], A in inf.. -1, B in   0..sup, C in   0..sup ;
Ts = [A    ], Fs = [  B,C], A in   0..sup, B in inf.. -1, C in inf.. -1 ;
Ts = [A,  C], Fs = [  B  ], A in   0..sup, B in inf.. -1, C in   0..sup ;
Ts = [A,B  ], Fs = [    C], A in   0..sup, B in   0..sup, C in inf.. -1 ;
Ts = [A,B,C], Fs = [     ], A in   0..sup, B in   0..sup, C in   0..sup .
```

---

#### Edit 2015-06-02

What if we used the SWI-Prolog library predicate [`partition/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=partition/4) in above query?

```
?- partition(#=<(0),[A,B,C],Ts,Fs).
Ts = [A,B,C], Fs = [], A in 0..sup, B in 0..sup, C in 0..sup.
```

We would lose 7 out of 8 solutions because `partition/4` is not monotone!

Comment: `#=<(X, Y, Truth) :- X #=< Y #<==> B, ( B = 0, Truth = false ; B = 1, Truth = true ).` (provided there is indexing for `B = 0 ; B = 1`)

Comment: `tpartition/4` in place of `partitionlist/4`?

Comment: @false. Sure, why not? What does the `t` in `tfilter` etc actually stand for btw?-)