# Finding the k'th occurence of a given element

Tags: prolog

I just started in Prolog and have the problem:

> (a) Given a list L, an object X, and a positive integer K, it returns
>   the position  of the K-th occurrence of X in L if X appears at least K
>   times in L otherwise 0.
>
> The goal `pos([a,b,c,b],b,2,Z)` should succeed with the answer `Z = 4`.

So far I have:

```
pos1([],H,K,F).
pos1([H],H,1,F).
pos1([H|T],H,K,F):- NewK is K - 1, pos1(T,H,NewK,F), F is F + 1.
pos1([H|T],X,K,F):- pos1(T,X,K,F).
```

But I can't figure out why I'm getting:

```
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you actually consulting the file?

Comment: I'm loading it straight from the file

Comment: What command are you using to load "straight from the file"?

Comment: I'm just clicking on my .pl file, and it loads it in SWI

Comment: So this is Windows? When I load your code into SWI Prolog I don't get that error at all. I get `ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`. Are you sure it's really consulting your file when you click on it?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7. Hm, that's strange.

Comment: Aw, I fixed it. I'm getting the same error, now.

Comment: You get the right error because you have `F is F + 1` and `F` is never instantiated. Anything on the right hand side of an `is` must be fully instantiated. In addition, you cannot re-assign a value to a variable in prolog once it's bound.

Comment: So how can I accumulate F?

Comment: you make a new one, `F1 is F + 1`.

Comment: How would I return F at the end?

Comment: by maintaining another argument to a predicate, and unifying it with the final value of `F`. Like is done for `L2` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

We define `pos/4` based on [`(#>)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html), [`(#=)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html), [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915), and [`(#<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915):

```
pos(Xs,E,K,P) :-
   K #> 0,
   pos_aux(Xs,E,K,1,P).

pos_aux([X|Xs],E,K,P0,P) :-
   P0+1 #= P1,
   if_(dif(X,E),
       pos_aux(Xs,E,K,P1,P),
       if_(K #< 2,
           P0 = P,
           (K0+1 #= K,
            pos_aux(Xs,E,K0,P1,P)))).
```

Sample query as given by the OP:

```
?- X = b, N = 2, pos([a,b,c,b],X,N,P).
X = b, N = 2, P = 4.                     % succeeds deterministically
```

How about the following more general query?

```
?- pos([a,b,c,b],X,N,P).
  X = a, N = 1, P = 1
; X = b, N = 1, P = 2
; X = b, N = 2, P = 4                    % (exactly like in above query)
; X = c, N = 1, P = 3
; false.
```

Comment: check out corner case. does `P=0` even make sense in "not found often enough" cases?

Comment: nice! (p.s.: one last `is/2` unintentionally remained in `pos_aux/5`!)

Comment: @mat. Actually I'm somewhat on the fence regarding the corner case... Does it even make a lot of sense? What's your take on this?

Comment: For didactic reasons alone, I would always favour the more declarative predicate when in doubt. I would also always suggest using `dif/2` instead of `(\==)/2` etc., even in cases where the result is the same: This is simply to advertise the more general solutions.

Comment: @mat. Thx! It's for the Greater Good!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a high-level approach to it, trading the efficiency of the resulting code for the ease of development:

```prolog
pos(L,X,K,P):-
   numerate(L,X,LN,1),  %// [A1,A2,A3...] -> [A1-1,A2-2,A3-3...], where Ai = X.
   ( drop1(K,LN,[X-P|_]) -> true ; P=0 ).
```

Now we just implement the two new predicates. *`drop1(K,L,L2)`* drops `K-1` elements from `L`, so we're left with `L2`:

```prolog
drop1(K,L2,L2):- K<2, !.
drop1(K,[_|T],L2):- K1 is K-1, drop1(K1,T,L2).
```

*`numerate(L,X,LN,I)`* adds an `I`-based index to each element of `L`, but keeps only `X`s:

```prolog
numerate([],_,[],_).
numerate([A|B],X,R,I):- I1 is I+1, ( A=X -> R=[A-I|C] ; R=C ), numerate(B,X,C,I1).
```

Testing:

```prolog
5 ?- numerate([1,b,2,b],b,R,1).
R = [b-2, b-4].

6 ?- pos([1,b,2,b],b,2,P).
P = 4.

7 ?- pos([1,b,2,b],b,3,P).
P = 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your code, without changing the logic, that seems already simple enough.
Just added a 'top level' handler, passing to actual worker pos1/4 and testing if worked, else returning 0 - a debatable way in Prolog, imo is better to allow to fail, I hope you will appreciate how adopting this (see comments) simplified your code...

```
pos(L,X,K,F):- pos1(L,X,K,F) -> true ; F=0.

% pos1([],H,K,F). useless: let it fail
% pos1([H],H,1,F). useless: already handled immediatly bottom
pos1([H|T],H,K,P):- K==1 -> P=1 ; NewK is K - 1, pos1(T,H,NewK,F), P is F + 1.
pos1([_|T],X,K,P):- pos1(T,X,K,F),P is F+1.
```

I hope you're allowed to use the if/then/else construct. Anyway, yields

```
7 ?- pos([a,b,c,b],b,2,Z).
Z = 4.

8 ?- pos([a,b,c,b],b,3,Z).
Z = 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. An outer predicate (this one enforces the specified constraints) that invokes an inner worker predicate:

```
kth( L , X , K , P ) :-
  is_list( L ) ,            % constraint: L must be a list
  nonvar(X) ,               % constriant: X must be an object
  integer(K) , K > 0        % constraint: K must be a positive integer
  kth( Ls , X , K , 1 , P ) % invoke the worker predicate with its accumulator seeded to 1
  .                         % easy!
```

`is_list/2` ensures you've got a list:

```
is_list(X) :- var(X) , !, fail .
is_list([]).
is_list([_|_]).
```

The predicate that does all the work is this one:

```
kth( []     , _ , _ , _ , 0 ) .      % if we hit the end of the list, P is 0.
kth( [X|Ls] , X , K , K , K ) :- ! . % if we find the Kth desired element, succeed (and cut: we won't find another Kth element)
kth( [_|Ls] , X , K , N , P ) :-     % otherwise
  N < K ,                            % - if we haven't got to K yet ...
  N1 is N+1 ,                        % - increment our accumulator , and
  kth(Ls,X,K,N1,P)                   % - recurse down.
  .                                  % easy!
```

Though the notion of returning 0 instead of failure is Not the Prolog Way, if you ask me.