# Prolog code to drop the nth element of the list

Tags: prolog

I wrote Prolog code for my assignment to drop the nth element of the give list.

I made a predicate called `remove/3` which removes an element from the list by its number, and another predicate called `drop2/4` which calls the `remove/3` predicate by only the numbers who are divisible by N.

But there is a small logical error as it only removes 1 element from the list which is the last element which is divisible by N. I guess this is because when I call the `remove/3` predicate with the list L and X it adds all the elements to X then remove element number N, however, L remains the same, so when I call `remove/3` again with another N, it doesn't continue on the previous edit, so the previous element which was deleted is restored, so that's why only the last element is deleted.

Query example:

```
drop([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k], 3, X).
```

Result should be: `X = [a,b,d,e,g,h,k]`

```
drop(L, N, X):-
    drop2(L, N, X, N).

drop2(_, _, _, 1).

drop2(L, N, X, C):-
    N mod C =:= 0,
    remove(L, N, X),
    Z is C-1,
    drop2(L, N, X, Z).

drop2(L, N, X, C):-
    Z is C-1,
    drop2(L, N, X, Z).

remove([_|T], 1, T).
remove([H|T1], N, [H|T2]):-
    N > 1,
    Z is N - 1,
    remove(T1, Z, T2).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog program that deletes every n-th element from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439360/prolog-program-that-deletes-every-n-th-element-from-a-list)

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko it's not a duplicate, the algorithm i'm using is totally different, and i just wanna fix my small error not to get a whole new code

Comment: The error may not be small. One primary issue is that when you first query `drop2(L, N, X, N)` from `drop/3`, `X` is uninstantiated, which is good because drop2 queries `remove(L, N, X)` which will attempt to remove the Nth element from `L` yielding `X`. But then it queries `drop2(L, N, X, Z)` recursively and now `X` is already instantiated. So the next time remove is queried, it will likely fail and continue to do so since it can't re-instantiate `X`.

Comment: Another issue is that `N mod C =:= 0` will occur exactly once in the entire recursive sequence as `C` descends to `1` since `C` counts down from `N` to `1`. This would be enough of a reason why it only removes one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems complicated to me. You could just say

```
drop(Xs,N,Rs) :-
  integer(N) ,
  N > 0 ,
  drop(Xs,1,N,Rs)
  .
```

where your helper predicate `drop/4` is

```
drop( []     , _ , _ , [] ) .
drop( [X|Xs] , P , N , Rs ) :-
  ( 0 =:= P mod N -> R1 = Rs ; [X|R1] = Rs ) ,
  P1 is P+1 ,
  drop(Xs,P1,N,R1)
  .
```

or the equivalent

```
drop( []     , _ , _ , [] ) .
drop( [X|Xs] , P , N , [X|Rs] ) :- 0 =\= P mod N , P1 is P+1 , drop(Xs,P1,N,Rs) .
drop( [_|Xs] , P , N ,    Rs  ) :- 0 =:= P mod N , P1 is P+1 , drop(Xs,P1,N,Rs) .
```

or even

```
drop( []     , _ , _ , []     ) .
drop( [_|Xs] , P , P ,    Rs  ) :-         P1 is   1 , drop(Xs,P1,N,Rs) .
drop( [X|Xs] , P , N , [X|Rs] ) :- P < N , P1 is P+1 , drop(Xs,P1,N,Rs) .
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for writing recursive code... simply use [`append/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3), [`length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2), and [`same_length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/search?for=same_length%2F2)!

```
list_nth1_dropped(As,N1,Bs) :-
   same_length(As,[_|Bs]),
   append(Prefix,[_|Suffix],As),
   length([_|Prefix],N1),
   append(Prefix,Suffix,Bs).
```

Here's the query the OP gave:

```
?- Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k],
   list_nth1_dropped(Xs,3,Ys).
  Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k],
  Ys = [a,b,  d,e,f,g,h,i,k]
; false.
```

How about a more general query?

```
?- list_nth1_dropped([a,b,c,d,e,f],N,Xs).
  N = 1, Xs = [  b,c,d,e,f]
; N = 2, Xs = [a,  c,d,e,f]
; N = 3, Xs = [a,b,  d,e,f]
; N = 4, Xs = [a,b,c,  e,f]
; N = 5, Xs = [a,b,c,d,  f]
; N = 6, Xs = [a,b,c,d,e  ]
; false.
```