# How to remove sub-lists in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, sublist

Can someone help me, please? I need to solve this problem in prolog and I don't know how...

"Given a list of integer numbers. Remove all sub-lists formed from decreases elements."

Comment: Can you show some attempt? Please read the [Stackoverflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) regarding how to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 3):

We remove descending sublists in three steps:

1. separate decreasing and non-decreasing parts (using
   [`splitlistIfAdj/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and [`(#=<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915))

   ```
   ?- splitlistIfAdj(#=<,[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4,3,2,1 , 2 , 3 , 4,3,2,1 , 2 ],Xs1).
   Xs1 =                 [[1],[2],[3],[4,3,2,1],[2],[3],[4,3,2,1],[2]].
   ```
2. exclude non-singleton lists (using [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915), [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord), and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915))

   ```
   ?- tfilter(\[_|T]^(T=[]),[[1],[2],[3],[4,3,2,1],[2],[3],[4,3,2,1],[2]],Xs2).
   Xs2 =                    [[1],[2],[3],          [2],[3],          [2]].
   ```
3. map singleton lists to items (using [`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) and [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord))

   ```
   ?- maplist(\[H|_]^H^true,[[1],[2],[3],[2],[3],[2]],Xs).
   Xs =                     [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 2 ].
   ```

---

Let's put it together!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

descending_removed(Xs0,Xs) :-
   splitlistIfAdj(#=<,Xs0,Xs1),
   tfilter(\[_|T]^(T=[]),Xs1,Xs2),
   maplist(\[H|_]^H^true,Xs2,Xs).
```

Here are some queries:

```
?- descending_removed([1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3,2,3,2].

?- descending_removed([4,3,2,1,0],Xs).
Xs = [].

?- descending_removed([1,2,3,4],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3,4].

?- descending_removed([1,2,3,  4,3,3,2,2,1],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3].

?- descending_removed([1,2,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3,4].
```

Answer (score 3):

We can improve [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31896704/4609915) by using [`tchoose/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953695/4609915) instead of `tfilter/3` and `maplist/3`, removing descending sublists in *two* steps---not three:

1. separate decreasing and non-decreasing parts (using [`splitlistIfAdj/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and [`(#=<)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059035/4609915))

   ```
   ?- splitlistIfAdj(#=<,[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4,3,2,1 , 2 , 3 , 4,3,2,1 , 2 ],Xs1).
   Xs1 =                 [[1],[2],[3],[4,3,2,1],[2],[3],[4,3,2,1],[2]].
   ```
2. filter singleton lists and map to items (using [`tchoose/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953695/4609915), [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord), and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915))

   ```
   ?- tchoose(\[H|T]^H^(T=[]),[[1],[2],[3],[4,3,2,1],[2],[3],[4,3,2,1],[2]],Xs).
   Xs =                       [ 1 , 2 , 3 ,           2 , 3 ,           2 ].
   ```

Let's put it together!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

descending_removed(Xs0,Xs) :-
   splitlistIfAdj(#=<,Xs0,Xs1),
   tchoose(\[H|T]^H^(T=[]),Xs1,Xs).
```

Same queries, same results:

```
?- descending_removed([1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3,2,3,2].

?- descending_removed([4,3,2,1,0],Xs).
Xs = [].

?- descending_removed([1,2,3,4],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3,4].

?- descending_removed([1,2,3,  4,3,3,2,2,1],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3].

?- descending_removed([1,2,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3,4].
```

Comment: Which result it provides to query "descending_removed([1,2,3,3,2,4,3,3,2,2,5],R)." ? (sorry, no lambda package to test by myself).

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: Which Prolog system are you using? You should be able to copy-paste to module-free version into any conforming system.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with some sample list of numbers:

```
1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2
```

After eliminating all decreasing sublists we should have

```
1 2 3 2 3 2
```

How could this be done? I would propose going through the list and observing how the "output" is generated when looking at group of numbers:

```
A B C
  1 2   -> output 1
1 2 3   -> output 2
2 3 4   -> output 3
3 4 3   -> output none
4 3 2   -> output none
3 2 1   -> output none
2 1 2   -> output none
1 2 3   -> output 2
2 3 4   -> output 3
3 4 3   -> output none
4 3 2   -> output none
3 2 1   -> output none
2 1 2   -> output none
1 2     -> output 2
```

What we see is that we output number from middle column B only when A < B < C. So this is what we can do: we can go through entire list and check number triples. If the're sorted then we output B.

```
remove_dec([], []).
remove_dec(Input, Output) :-
    min_list(Input, Min),
    remove_dec0([ Min | Input ], Output).
remove_dec0([ A, B, C | Input], [ B | Output ]) :-
    A =< B, B =< C,
    remove_dec0([ B, C | Input], Output).
remove_dec0([ _, B, C | Input], Output) :-
    remove_dec0([ B, C | Input], Output).
remove_dec0([A, B], [B]) :-
    A =< B.
remove_dec0([A, B], []) :-
    A > B.
```

Sample input and output:

```
?- remove_dec([1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2],R).
R = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2] .

?- remove_dec([4,3,2,1,0],R).
R = [] ;
false.

?- remove_dec([1,2,3,4],R).
R = [1, 2, 3, 4] .
```

Comment: @repeat, the clause you quote doesn't exist. Are you suggesting to reaplce `A =< B, B =< C` with `once(A > B;B > C)`? I've checked and it resulted in giving wrong results.

Comment: I meant the clause `remove_dec0([ _, B, C | Input], Output) :-
    remove_dec0([ B, C | Input], Output).` That should better be: `remove_dec0([A,B,C|Input],Output) :- once(A > B;B > C), remove_dec0([B,C|Input],Output).` so this clause and the one above it become mutually exclusive (without using a cut on that level).

Comment: @Grzegorz: cut after A =< B, B =< C.

Answer (score 1):

What about (using same names and test than in previous answers):

```
descending_removed(L,R) :- dr(a,L,R).

dr(_,[],[]).

dr(DIR,[A|Q],R) :-
  ( [B|_]=Q, A>B ->  
        dr(d,Q,R)
  ;
        dr(a,Q,T), ( DIR=a -> R=[A|T]; R=T )
  ).
```

verification:

```
test :-
  descending_removed([1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2],[1,2,3,2,3,2]),
  descending_removed([4,3,2,1,0],[]),
  descending_removed([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]),
  descending_removed([1,2,3,4,3,3,2,2,1],[1,2,3]),
  descending_removed([1,2,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],[1,2,3,4]),
  descending_removed([1],[1]).
```

gives following result:

```
[debug]  ?- test.
true ;
false.
```

If we want to cover the case of two consecutive equal values, with the interpretation they doesn't changes the curve tendency, we can define:

```
descending_removed(L,R) :- dr(a,L,R).

dr(_,[],[]).

dr(DIR,[A|Q],R) :-
  ( [B|_]=Q, A>B ->  
        dr(d,Q,R)
  ; [B|_]=Q, A=B ->  
        dr(DIR,Q,T), ( DIR=a -> R=[A|T]; R=T )   
  ;   
        dr(a,Q,T), ( DIR=a -> R=[A|T]; R=T )
  ).
```

that produces following answers:

```
descending_removed([1,2,2,2,3,4,3,3,2,2,1],R).
R = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3] ;
false

descending_removed([1,2,3,3,2,4,3,3,2,2,5],R).
R = [1, 2, 3, 5]
false
```